# withEqualsForType() where type is the type of a property in the expected object

Tags: assertj

I'm trying to compare two different types, `DTO` and `Entity`. `DTO` has:

```
private String id;
private String teamId;
private String conferenceId;
```

`Entity` has:

```
private UUID id;
private UUID teamId;
private UUID conferenceId;
```

In my test I have:

```
DTO actual = mapper.entityToDto(entity);

assertThat(actual)
  .usingRecursiveComparison()
  .isEqualTO(entity);
```

I'd like to use `withEqualsForType((stringId, uuidId) -> comparison, UUID.class)` but that doesn't work as I get an error about no method for signature UUID.class, UUID.class.

I also tried `withEqualsForType((stringId, uuidID) -> comparison, String.class)` but got a similar message about String.class.

Is there a way to use a custom equals based on the type in the expected object?

Comment: Wy do you need type-based equals if you have all strings at one case and all UUIDs at another case? You would better go with equalsForFields

Comment: @AlexeyR.: Because I don't want to have to list every field where I need this comparison. If I want all String to UUID comparisons to be handled the same way I'd prefer to just register one type-based equals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported at the moment but you should be able to register a `BiPredicate<String, Object>` for String that would check if expected is a UUID and in this case call `toString()` on it.

Have a look at https://github.com/assertj/assertj/issues/3165 which is similar.